# DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemSource Binding Doesn't work

Tags: wpf, binding

In all of the examples of DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemSource comming from the Resources.
Couldn't it be binding directly to a list in the CodeBehind ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean with binding directly to a list in the CodeBehind.

You can declare the column with...

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="m_column" ../>
```

and then in code-behind set the ItemsSource...

```
m_column.ItemsSource=yourItemsSource
```

However **you can not directly use the binding in XAML**, something like:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=YourElement}}"/>
```

because `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is not a part of the visual tree.

There are workarounds for this. The most simple is using a DataGridTemplateColumn and placing the ComboBoxes directly in the edit-DataTemplate. If you use a ViewModel, you can provide the data through it. Otherwise look [here](http://joemorrison.org/blog/2009/02/17/excedrin-headache-35401281-using-combo-boxes-with-the-wpf-datagrid/) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx) for workarounds.

Comment: I found the extend DataGridComboBoxColumn approach in Joe Morrison's blog (link above) to be particularly useful for binding with view models.