# Style DataGridTemplateColumn to Match DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn, datagridtemplatecolumn

**EDIT (clarification of requirements)**

I have a `DataGrid` as shown below.  The values in the "Field Name To Store Old EmpNo" column change based on the value selected in "New EmpNo Rule" column.  To accommodate this, each item in the `DataGrid` `ItemsSource` has its own `TableNameForOldDataCollection`.  I need to bind to this `TableNameForOldDataCollection` and not a static property that cannot change.

If there is a way to do this binding while using `DataGridComboBoxTemplate` I would prefer that.  If not, I would like to know if it is possible to template the `DataGridTemplateColumn`/`ComboBox` to match that of the `DataGridComboBoxTemplate`

**OP**

I have a scenario where I am using `DataGridComboBoxColumn` for one of the `DataGrid` columns.  In another column, I need to use the `DataGridTemplateColumn`, with a `ComboBox`, to properly bind to a dynamic ItemSource in the VM.

The `DataGridComboBoxColumn` ("New EmpNo Rule") is styled differently than the `DataGridTemplateColumn`, with a `ComboBox` ("Field Name To Store Old EmpNo") as shown here:

[image]

How can I  style the `DataGridTemplateColumn`/`ComboBox` to match the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, particularly how the combobox is hidden when the actual cell is not selected (like the second row of "New EmpNo Rule").

**EDIT (added `DataGrid` code):**

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
             <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StaticEmpNoRuleCollection" Source="{Binding EmpNoRuleCollection}" />                
        </ResourceDictionary>        
    </UserControl.Resources>

....

                <DataGrid Name="DataGrid_MultiCompanyInfo"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Model.EmpNoOptionsCollection}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmpNoOptions}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>

                        <!-- Company -->
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" 
                                            Binding="{Binding Company}"
                                            IsReadOnly="True" />

                        <!-- New EmpNo Rule -->
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="New EmpNo Rule"
                                                Width="200"
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StaticEmpNoRuleCollection}}"
                                                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedEmpNoRule, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                        <!-- Field Name To Store Old EmpNo -->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Field Name To&#x0a;Store Old EmpNo"
                                                Width="150" >
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox Name="OldEmpNo_ComboBox"
                                              Margin="-5,0,0,0"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding TableNameForOldDataCollection}"
                                              SelectedValue="{Binding TableNameForOldData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        ...

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Could you please post your DataGridTemplateColumn Code?

Comment: @Kirenenko Please see edit to OP.

Comment: I think that the correct way to go is to use DataGridComboBoxColumn on "Old EmpNo" to, but you should correctly bind, using `RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"`.

Comment: @Kirenenko I originally went this route which didn't work. According to a number of different articles I have found, you cannot do what you are suggesting because DataGridComboBoxColumn is not a part of the visual tree (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659970/datagridcomboboxcolumn-itemsource-binding-doesnt-work).  This is why I have to use the DataGridTemplateColumn.  This particular column's selectable values changes based on other columns selected value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Bind data to DataGridComboBoxColumn in DataGrid using MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563325/how-to-bind-data-to-datagridcomboboxcolumn-in-datagrid-using-mvvm)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that DataGridComboBoxColumn is not in the same visual tree, you can use a [BindingProxy](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/):

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

XAML resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

XAML binding(not on the visual tree):

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Data.TableNameForOldDataCollection, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Totally different solution...Looks a little hackish, but I've tested it an it works:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Field Name To&#x0a;Store Old EmpNo" Width="150"
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding TableNameForOldData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding TableNameForOldDataCollection}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding TableNameForOldDataCollection}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Also I think it is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3564118/5147720), so I will flag it.

Comment: While I like this option of providing a bindable collection, it doesn't work for my scenario (see added requirements in OP).  It appears to bind to a collection on the DataGrid itself and not a property in each of the items in EmpNoOptionsCollection.  If I am missing something and this would work to fulfill the requirements can you please explain further?

Comment: I thought that your `TableNameForOldDataCollection` was on your main DataContext/ViewModel. Just tell me where is the object to bind, because you have to point the proxy "Data" to it.

Comment: The `TableNameForOldDataCollection` is on each individual item in `Model.EmpNoOptionsCollection`.   Each item in the `DataGrid` has its own copy of `TableNameForOldDataCollection` because the values can change based on the value of `StaticEmpNoRuleCollection`

Comment: Woah...Now I understand...This is some kind of `ItemsourceBindIngCeption`. Let me check If I can do something, but not so sure...